# Encode specific part of string and load it to xml

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

When I load string xml into XmlDocument object, it throws

> '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character.

```
string xml= Request.Form["webformfield"] + string.Empty;

// it will read the input from webform in encoded format
e.g:
&lt;Models&gt;&lt;Model ModelID=&quot;F2434&quot; ModelName=&quot;FTest 1 &amp; Income MP&quot; /&gt;

try around: 
//decoded the whole string
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Server.HtmlDecode(models, sw); // this is an internal method of the framework.
models = sw.ToString();

after decoding the string, the string will be stored below
//string xml = "<Models><Model ModelId=\"124\" ModelNameWithSpecialCHars=\"Test1 <> & \"' characters \"/><Model ModelId=\"124\" ModelNameWithSpecialCHars=\"Test2 <> & \"' characters \"/></Models>";

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
```

I have changed xml string manually at runtime and it worked. Changed value of ModelNameWithSpecialCHars attribute from the string.
added string image, because when I written the encoded specials characters, it was showing it in decoded format. find the below code.

Changed string: [image]

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
        Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Is there any way I can encode only specific part of string. e.g

```
string xml = "<Models><Model ModelId=\"124\" ModelNameWithSpecialCHars=\"Tes <> & \"' characters \"/></Models>";
```

in the above string, I need to encode only value of ModelNameWithSpecialCHars attribute. ("Tes <> & "')

Comment: Who does this encoding in the first place? Is that code by you or someone else in the html document?

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just put the part that needs encoding in a separate variable and use the [`WebUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode?view=net-7.0) method (found in `System.Net`):

```
string bad_xml = "Tes <> & \"' characters ";
bad_xml = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(bad_xml);
string xml = "<Models><Model ModelId=\"124\" ModelNameWithSpecialCHars=\"" + bad_xml + "\"/Model></Models>"
```

although you might find it cleaner to add elements and attributes using the `XmlDocument` class since you want to have an `XmlDocument` in the end anyway, and it will encode text for you into valid XML, which has slightly different escaping requirements (although for your test string they are equivalent).

Comment: Hello, The problem is this ModelNameWithSpecialCHars value comes from asp.net webform. so how to extract and how to encode that specific value is the challenge. 

and this <Model ModelId=\"124\" ModelNameWithSpecialCHars=\"" + bad_xml + "\"/> model tag can be multiple. so for every model tag I need to encode the attibute value of ModelNameWithSpecialCHars.

Comment: @Desmond Show the code where you construct the xml from user input. Do you do that by just using string concatenation? You should use XMLDocument to build the xml from user input in the first place

Comment: @Desmond so you are receiving invalid XML from the provider? No, there's no way to "encode" part of a string. you'll need to either fix the provider or  parse the string yourself into parts so you can encode the parts individually. Do you receive the _entire_ xml string from the provided or just parts that you put into an XML document?

Comment: @DStanley I just edited the description again. could you please just check once. just the code part

Comment: @DStanley how can we parse the string into parts and encode parts individually? any hints would be great help/

Comment: @NineBerry I have edited the description. can you please check the code once

Comment: You are receiving invalid XML as input. If you don't know _where_ the XML is invalid there's no way to intelligently break the XML into "good" and "bad" parts to encode the "bad" parts. You' have to do something ugly like looking for quotes to represent attribute values, although you'll have the same problem as a parser - how do you know if a quote is part of the attribute value or not? Where is the input coming from? I see that it's a form variable - Is it entered by a user, or assembled from JavaScript, or something else?

Comment: @DStanley ModelNameWithSpecialCHars this attribute value is entered by user.

Comment: Just the attribute value or the entire XML string? If it's just the attribute then you can encode that before creating the XML string. If they enter the entire XML string then they'll need to use valid XML.

Comment: @DStanley just the attribute value from the entire encoded string.  Because when user enters the value it gets saved into string in encoded format. Please see the description example 3rd line of code.   Or if it’s not feasible then is there any way to encode it while reading from web form

Comment: No, I'm asking if the user just enters in `Tes <> & \"' characters` in one field in the form and it gets added to the XML somehow or the entire XML string (e.g. `<Models><Model ModelId="124" ModelNameWithSpecialCHars="Tes <> & "' characters "/></Models>`. If they enter in the XML it will be very difficult to extract the attribute value to encode it before the entire string is encoded. If the attribute value is in a form field than it might be possible,m but you nay have to change the form code.

Comment: @DStanley, attribute value is entered in the form field.

Comment: So can you get that field value instead of `webformfield`?